# Use Percentages instead of Vote Counts for Jquery Voting Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a voting system similar to stackoverflow, but instead of vote counts of **0, 1, -1.** I want to change it to **Not Rated, 0%, and 100%.** How can I accomplish this?

This is the tutorial i'm following:
http://janosgyerik.github.io/jquery-upvote/

And this is my html:

```
<div class="examples" id="examples"></div>
    <div id="templates" class="hidden">
        <div class="upvote">
            <a class="upvote" title="This is good stuff. Vote it up! (Click again to undo)"></a>
            <span class="count" title="Total number of votes"></span>
            <a class="downvote" title="This is not useful. Vote it down. (Click again to undo)"></a>



  <div class="examples" id="examples"></div>
    <div id="templates" class="hidden">
        <div class="upvote">
            <a class="upvote" title="This is good stuff. Vote it up! (Click again to undo)"></a>
            <span class="count" title="Total number of votes"></span>
            <a class="downvote" title="This is not useful. Vote it down. (Click again to undo)"></a>
```

And my javascript:

```
   function gen(target, cssClass, params) {
                var obj = $('#templates .upvote').clone();
                obj.addClass(cssClass);
                $(target).append(obj);
                return obj.upvote(params);
            }

            $(function() {
                    function gen_examples(params) {
                        gen('#examples', '', params);
                    }
                    function gen_unix(params) {
                        gen('#unix', 'upvote-unix', params);
                    }
                    function gen_programmers(params) {
                        gen('#programmers', 'upvote-programmers', params);
                    }
                    function gen_serverfault(params) {
                        gen('#serverfault', 'upvote-serverfault', params);
                    }
                    var functions = [gen_examples, gen_unix, gen_programmers, gen_serverfault];
                    for (var i in functions) {
                        var fun = functions[i];
                        fun();

                    }
            });


    ;(function($) {
        "use strict";
        var namespace = 'upvote';
        var dot_namespace = '.' + namespace;
        var upvote_css = 'upvote';
        var dot_upvote_css = '.' + upvote_css;
        var upvoted_css = 'upvote-on';
        var dot_upvoted_css = '.' + upvoted_css;
        var downvote_css = 'downvote';
        var dot_downvote_css = '.' + downvote_css;
        var downvoted_css = 'downvote-on';
        var dot_downvoted_css = '.' + downvoted_css;
        var star_css = 'star';
        var dot_star_css = '.' + star_css;
        var starred_css = 'star-on';
        var dot_starred_css = '.' + starred_css;
        var count_css = 'count';
        var dot_count_css = '.' + count_css;
        var enabled_css = 'upvote-enabled';

        function init(dom, options) {
            return dom.each(function() {
                var jqdom = $(this);
                methods.destroy(jqdom);

                var count = parseInt(jqdom.find(dot_count_css).text(), 10);
                count = isNaN(count) ? 0 : count;
                var initial = {
                    id: jqdom.attr('data-id'),
                    count: count,
                    upvoted: jqdom.find(dot_upvoted_css).size(),
                    downvoted: jqdom.find(dot_downvoted_css).size(),
                    starred: jqdom.find(dot_starred_css).size(),
                    callback: function() {}
                };

                var data = $.extend(initial, options);
                if (data.upvoted && data.downvoted) {
                    data.downvoted = false;
                }

                jqdom.data(namespace, data);
                render(jqdom);
                setupUI(jqdom);
            });
        }

        function setupUI(jqdom) {
            jqdom.find(dot_upvote_css).addClass(enabled_css);
            jqdom.find(dot_downvote_css).addClass(enabled_css);
            jqdom.find(dot_star_css).addClass(enabled_css);
            jqdom.find(dot_upvote_css).on('click.' + namespace, function() {
                jqdom.upvote('upvote');
            });
            jqdom.find('.downvote').on('click.' + namespace, function() {
                jqdom.upvote('downvote');
            });
            jqdom.find('.star').on('click.' + namespace, function() {
                jqdom.upvote('star');
            });
        }

        function _click_upvote(jqdom) {
            jqdom.find(dot_upvote_css).click();
        }

        function _click_downvote(jqdom) {
            jqdom.find(dot_downvote_css).click();
        }

        function _click_star(jqdom) {
            jqdom.find(dot_star_css).click();
        }

        function render(jqdom) {
            var data = jqdom.data(namespace);
            jqdom.find(dot_count_css).text(data.count);
            if (data.upvoted) {
                jqdom.find(dot_upvote_css).addClass(upvoted_css);
                jqdom.find(dot_downvote_css).removeClass(downvoted_css);
            } else if (data.downvoted) {
                jqdom.find(dot_upvote_css).removeClass(upvoted_css);
                jqdom.find(dot_downvote_css).addClass(downvoted_css);
            } else {
                jqdom.find(dot_upvote_css).removeClass(upvoted_css);
                jqdom.find(dot_downvote_css).removeClass(downvoted_css);
            }
            if (data.starred) {
                jqdom.find(dot_star_css).addClass(starred_css);
            } else {
                jqdom.find(dot_star_css).removeClass(starred_css);
            }
        }

        function callback(jqdom) {
            var data = jqdom.data(namespace);
            data.callback(data);
        }

        function upvote(jqdom) {
            var data = jqdom.data(namespace);
            if (data.upvoted) {
                data.upvoted = false;
                --data.count;
            } else {
                data.upvoted = true;
                ++data.count;
                if (data.downvoted) {
                    data.downvoted = false;
                    ++data.count;
                }
            }
            render(jqdom);
            callback(jqdom);
            return jqdom;
        }

        function downvote(jqdom) {
            var data = jqdom.data(namespace);
            if (data.downvoted) {
                data.downvoted = false;
                ++data.count;
            } else {
                data.downvoted = true;
                --data.count;
                if (data.upvoted) {
                    data.upvoted = false;
                    --data.count;
                }
            }
            render(jqdom);
            callback(jqdom);
            return jqdom;
        }

        function star(jqdom) {
            var data = jqdom.data(namespace);
            data.starred = ! data.starred;
            render(jqdom);
            callback(jqdom);
            return jqdom;
        }

        function count(jqdom) {
            return jqdom.data(namespace).count;
        }

        function upvoted(jqdom) {
            return jqdom.data(namespace).upvoted;
        }

        function downvoted(jqdom) {
            return jqdom.data(namespace).downvoted;
        }

        function starred(jqdom) {
            return jqdom.data(namespace).starred;
        }

        var methods = {
            init: init,
            count: count,
            upvote: upvote,
            upvoted: upvoted,
            downvote: downvote,
            downvoted: downvoted,
            starred: starred,
            star: star,
            _click_upvote: _click_upvote,
            _click_downvote: _click_downvote,
            _click_star: _click_star,
            destroy: destroy
        };

        function destroy(jqdom) {
            return jqdom.each(function() {
                $(window).unbind(dot_namespace);
                $(this).removeClass(enabled_css);
                $(this).removeData(namespace);
            });
        }

        $.fn.upvote = function(method) {  
            var args;
            if (methods[method]) {
                args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                args.unshift(this);
                return methods[method].apply(this, args);
            }
            if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
                args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                args.unshift(this);
                return methods.init.apply(this, args);
            }
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.upvote');
        };  
    })(jQuery);
```

Finally the css:

```
  .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
        .examples {
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .examples div.upvote {
            float: left;
        }

    div.upvote {
        text-align: center;
    }

    div.upvote a.upvote-enabled {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    div.upvote a {
        color: transparent;
        background-image: url('images/sprites-stackoverflow.png?v=1');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 41px;
        height: 25px;
    }

    div.upvote span.count {
        display: block;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: Arial, Liberation, Sans, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
        color: #555;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    div.upvote a.upvote {
        background-position: 0px -265px;
    }

    div.upvote a.upvote.upvote-on {
        background-position: 0px -230px;
    }

    div.upvote a.downvote {
        background-position: 0px -300px;
    }

    div.upvote a.downvote.downvote-on {
        background-position: 0px -330px;
    }


    div.upvote-serverfault a {
        background-image: url('images/sprites-serverfault.png?v=1');
    }

    div.upvote-meta-stackoverflow a {
        background-image: url('images/sprites-meta-stackoverflow.png?v=1');
    }

    div.upvote-superuser a {
        background-image: url('images/sprites-superuser.png?v=1');
    }

    div.upvote-unix a {
        background-image: url('images/sprites-unix.png?v=1');
        width: 42px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    div.upvote-unix a.upvote {
        background-position: 0px -237px;
    }

    div.upvote-unix a.upvote.upvote-on {
        background-position: 0px -198px;
    }

    div.upvote-unix a.downvote {
        background-position: 0px -281px;
    }

    div.upvote-unix a.downvote.downvote-on {
        background-position: 0px -319px;
    }

    div.upvote-unix a.star {
        width: 42px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: 0px -126px;
    }

    div.upvote-unix a.star.star-on {
        background-position: 0px -164px;
    }

    div.upvote-unix span.count {
        color: #333;
        line-height: 15px;
        padding: 9px 0;
        font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono","Bitstream Vera Sans Mono","Courier New",Courier,Consolas,"Andale Mono WT","Andale Mono","Lucida Console","Lucida Sans Typewriter",monospace;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }

    div.upvote-programmers a {
        background-image: url('images/sprites-programmers.png?v=1');
        width: 42px;
        height: 20px;
    }

    div.upvote-programmers a.upvote {
        background-position: 5px -248px;
    }

    div.upvote-programmers a.upvote.upvote-on {
        background-position: 5px -211px;
    }

    div.upvote-programmers a.downvote {
        background-position: 5px -282px;
    }

    div.upvote-programmers a.downvote.downvote-on {
        background-position: 5px -320px;
    }

    div.upvote-programmers a.star {
        width: 42px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: 6px -128px;
    }

    div.upvote-programmers a.star.star-on {
        background-position: 6px -166px;
    }

    div.upvote-programmers span.count {
        color: #333;
        line-height: 15px;
        padding: 5px 0 7px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: But how are u going to calculate percentage is it (VoteCount/No.OfUsers)/100. If yes then its pure mathematics.

Comment: Yea, thats how I want to calculate percentages. For now I only need upvote makes it 100% and downvote brings it down to 0% based on 1 user. The default should be not rated. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I think this is where you need to something function upvote(jqdom) {}

Comment: Can u create fiddle for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3ec67gne/ The up and down arrowns are not showing up on the fiddle, but this is the exact same code I'm using.

Comment: Did you take a look at it?

Comment: Yes I looked at it, You need to do everything in only two functions  .ie update and downvote. As a sinle used you can only upvote or downvote. You might need to take totalCount from server at page load(if u are saving it in db) and then do ur calculation in these two functions http://jsfiddle.net/3ec67gne/3/

Comment: Im not connecting to a server yet, but can you eleaborate on how to do this? I'm new at jquery, and I'm just trying to figure out how to add 0% for downvote and 100% for upvote with not rated as the default. Can this be done without a server and only on jquery?

Comment: Can you think of a solution?